# How to insert a rich edit control in MSVC 2015 MFC dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, richeditbox

I need to add a Right Edit control to MFC Dialog based application.

I am using MSVC 2015. On which on the Toolbox I can find "Rich Edit" as I used to find on MSVC 6.0

Comment: Wow, MS is up to 2105.  I just got the company to upgrade to 2017.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Should I upgrade my compiler?

Comment: No, don't upgrade.  MSVC 2105 is way more recent that what I have heard about.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: But I can't find Rich Edit there? on MFC Dialog based application?!

Comment: *as I used to find on MSVC 6.0* -- Visual Studio 2002, 2003, 2005, 2008, 2010, 2013, 2015, 2017.  With all of those renditions, it is not surprising that things could change.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for "Visual Studio 2015 MFC toolbox"?  Or you could try "Visual Studio 2105 MFC toolbox", depending on the version of Visual Studio you really have.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I searched on visual studio 2015 and on internet but didn't help.

Comment: I figured it out: Right clicked on the Toolbox and Reset the the toolbox then I got it there (RichEdit2).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out: Right clicked on the Toolbox and Reset the the toolbox then I got it there (RichEdit2).

I wish that this would be helpful for someone who got stuck in such trivial problem.

I think that something went wrong with the MSVC compiler. Thanks to "Reset" function.